Assembly not printing anything to the console
I am trying to make a simple hello world program in assembly, I use 64 bit Windows and I am calling printf in the assembly code. But it doesn't work, when I open the compiled program, it doesn't print anything and just closes. Here's the code:
; hello.asm
section .data
    hello db 'Hello, World!', 0   

section .text
    global main
    extern printf
    extern ExitProcess

main:
    mov rdi, hello       
    call printf          

    mov eax, 0           
    call ExitProcess     

This is my command to compile the assembly:
nasm -f win64 main.asm -o main.obj
And this is my command to link it:
gcc -o main.exe main.obj -lkernel32 -lmsvcrt

RDI isn't a standard register for passing params, did you want RCX instead? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention

Try adding a \n to your string.

josh poley, thank you, I changed the rdi to rcx and it worked!

Also you should allocate shadow space and align stack.

RDI is the first arg-passing register for x86-64 System V (Linux, Mac, etc).  For Windows x64 it's RCX, RDX, R8, R9 as @josh says.
